# React Js SetState is not working, what should be done in my code to fix it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update the set in a react component but there is no change after I update the value. What am I doing wrong

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pageNo: 0,
      Name: ""
    };
    this.openPage = this.openPage.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button className="tablink"> All Questions </button>
        <button
          className="tablink"
          onClick={() => {
            console.log("setting the state completed");
            this.setState(
              {
                pageNo: 1
              },
              console.log("StateChanged", this.state.pageNo)
            );
          }}
        >
          {" "}
          Home{" "}
        </button>

        <div id="Home" className="tabcontent">
          <h3> Home </h3>
        </div>
        <div id="AllQuestions" className="tabcontent">
          <h3> AllQuestions </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  openPage() {
    console.log("Function called");
    this.setState({
      pageNo: 2
    });
    console.log(this.state);
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
      tabcontent[i].style.display = "none"; // setting all tab divs to hide
    }

    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
      tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
    }

    document.getElementById(this.state.pageToLoad).style.display = "block";
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: ,Don't use setState inside render function.

Comment: you are using two different names, 1. pageNo , 2. pageToLoad  ..my guess is you wanted to use pageNo in place of pageToLoad...and store new page number you want to load in variable and then use it to update state and activate page

Comment: I was just trying things(checking if the source of my issue was due to me trying to edit string datatypes key value pairs) , I do want to use pageNo.

Comment: @VahidAkhtar can you tell me why I shouldn't, can you also tell me what is the other way to set the state because I do want to set different states based on different buttons that I click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        pageNo: 0,
        Name:''
    }

    this.openPage = this.openPage.bind(this);
}

StateChange = () => {
     console.log("setting the state completed");
            this.setState({
                pageNo: 1
            })

}

openPage(){
    console.log("Function called");
    this.setState({
        pageNo: 2
    });
    console.log(this.state);
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none"; // setting all tab divs to hide
    }

    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++){
        tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
    }

    document.getElementById(this.state.pageToLoad).style.display = "block";

}

render() {
     console.log("StateChanged", this.state.pageNo) //check this

    return (
    <div>

        <button className="tablink"> All Questions </button>
                                        {/*StateChange function*/}
        <button className="tablink" onClick={this.StateChange}> Home </button>

        <div id="Home" className = "tabcontent">
            <h3> Home </h3>
        </div>
        <div id="AllQuestions" className="tabcontent">
            <h3> AllQuestions </h3>
        </div>
    </div>);
}

}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you explain how can I pass arguments to the function that you created "StateChange" ?

Comment: (arg) => this.StateChange(arg)

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pageNo: false,
      Name: ''
    }
    this.handlePage = this.handlePage.bind(this);
  }

  handlePage() {
    this.setState({
      pageNo: !this.state.pageNo
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (<div>
      <button className="tablink" onClick={this.handlePage}> All Questions </button>
      <button className="tablink" onClick={this.handlePage}> Home </button>
      {this.state.pageNo ?
        <div id="AllQuestions" className="tabcontent">
          <h3> AllQuestions </h3>
        </div> :
        <div id="Home" className="tabcontent">
          <h3> Home </h3>
        </div>}
    </div>);
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```